# How can I use onDisconnect with python?

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Pyrebase for my app, I think [Pyrebase](https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase) is using Rest API to interact with Firebase. So is it possible to use `onDisconnect()` using Rest API?

Answer (score 1):

Pyrebase doesn't yet support that. I was going to suggest that you create a Pull Request, but I saw that [you already did](https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase/issues/238).

That's probably because the [REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/start) also doesn't support it yet (if it does, it is not documented anywhere). I've also looked at all of the other [Helper Libraries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/start#section-library) and none of them implement the `onDisconnect()` or any kind of workaround.